# MDX intrinsic member property null

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I want to create an `MDX` dataset for a filter in a `SSRS` report, by using the `MDX` query below. For one member in my dimension the properties return NULL. The problem is, this type of script works perfect on all my other dimensions, just the first member for the year 2014/25 returns `NULL` for its properties. Any ideas?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
    [Time].[Fiscalyear].CurrentMember.Name 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
    [Time].[Fiscalyear].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption]
   ,[Measures].[ParameterLevel]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[Time].[Fiscalyear].[All].Children ON ROWS
FROM [Cube];
```

The result is the following:
[image]

Comment: for the date 2014/15 are there any results in the cube?

Comment: Yes, there is data for 2014/15. Cube and the Dimension works perfect in every other Tool like PowerView etc. Just SSRS is driving me nuts...

Comment: odd behaviour - I'm unsure why - I've starred as interested to know why this is happening